# MS EntityFramework: how to split entity with inheritance? Using of discriminator

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, mapping

I have table name Transaction in the DB. I want to have 2 subclasses TransactionA and TransactionB. I've made it as described here: http://www.robbagby.com/entity-framework/entity-framework-modeling-table-per-hierarchy-inheritance/comment-page-1/#comment-607

The problem is I need to use the field that is discriminator here (see the example, it's PersonCategory there). But it has to be deleted after that I cannot use it.

How to solve this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a discriminator its only usage is to map record to either `TransactionA` or `TransactionB`. It cannot be set in the application. It is set if you insert `TransactionA` instance or `TransactionB` instance and record. It also cannot be updated because object of one type cannot change to object of other type - if you need such logic you cannot model it as inheritance.

Comment: I don't want neither set nor update. I need only to show the value. Why cannot I do that? If I really CANNOT how to show its value to user?

Comment: Simply you cannot. That is restriction inside entity framework. If you want to show value just test type of the entity and show according value.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand your "just test type of the entity and show according value". What does it mean?

Comment: Something like `if (entity is TransactionA) value = "abc"` because that is exactly supposed usage - you made your mapping object oriented so behave like that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is used as a EF helper to identify type of the specific type of the object. One disadvantage is that approach is every field should be a nullable field and tables are not normalized. However, no joins are involved hence, it is fast approach. Table per type is relatively good approach you have two classes TransactionA and TransactionB with generic class called Transaction.Although, you have to do join as a result of that, performance is not that great compair to earlier approach.